# Opening A File With Batch Programming

Tags: windows, batch

So i'm making a launcher for a game with a modded version and a vanilla version. I finally was able to open the game, but the game does not respond! I used: `start "Game Title" "Path\Game.exe"`

The game is Isaac: Rebirth. The games runs fine when I run it through a shortcut, so i'm not sure if there are any command line arguments. The game does not have a launcher. The shortcut does not have any command line arguements either.

Comment: Which game are we talking about? It might be that the game requires command line arguements normally supplied via a launcher. Also, can you confirm that it works as intended if you start it the normal way?

Comment: The game is Isaac: Rebirth. The games runs fine and i usually run it through a shortcut, so i'm not sure if there are any arguments. The game does not have a launcher.

Comment: So what are the shortcut properties? Right click shortcut > Properties > Target etc

Comment: The shortcut is normal, after the path there are no arguments or anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably need to the change the work directory in the batch before starting the executable. Check the start directory in the shortcut and then add a cd to this location as first line in the batch file. Else it will likely end up starting the executable with your user profile directory or windows\system32 as working directory which can cause problems depending on the way the software was written.

Comment: Thank You! I used cd to get to the path and when I needed to open the game I just had to use start "Title" "Game.exe". This worked, thanks everyone for helping!